# In Docker is there a way to maintain (updateable and trackable) "aliases" for images?

Tags: docker, version-control

In a project with several references to certain Docker-images I want to provide a versionable (i.e git-trackable) way to use common names for Docker-images.

Currently at several places in an existing project some Bash/Python-scripts, Docker-files or Jenkins-files I'm referencing e.g. `busybox:latest`. Now I want to use readable names for *unique* images without redundancy instead.

As far as I understand I could use my own registry, provide a readable tag and just use the tag or the right repo-digest:

```
docker pull busybox:latest
docker tag busybox:latest my_registry/busybox:default
docker push my_registry/busybox:default

# use
docker pull busybox@sha256:dca712...86b  <- has to be maintained manually
# or
docker pull my_registry/busybox:default <- not updateable or not unique for given commit
```

But now I also want the distinct sha1s behind also be *update-able* and *git-trackable* (without having to redundantly write the sha everywhere). Maybe I'm not using the correct wording but what I need could be achieved by using a text-file containing some sort of "aliases", e.g.

**docker_aliases.txt**:

```
my_registry/busybox_default sha256:dafhs3ca712...3486b
my_registry/ubuntu-20.04 sha256:6a507907bd4e...a50
```

which could then somehow be used with all Docker-calls which involve pulling images and would allow me to

- use `my_registry/busybox_default` as image specifier at *all* places
- have *one* place to update those aliases
- which could be tracked by git (very important)

It feels like everyone who's maintaining some larger CI should come across this problem. Is there a general solution for this?

Comment: How about a `Dockerfile` with just a FROM directive?

Comment: I wanted to write "did your read the question at all?", but then I understood, what you meant :)
I'll give it a try but maybe you should turn your comment into an answer

Comment: https://xkcd.com/530/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Dockerfile with just a `FROM` directive pointing at the image you want to use. Track it with git. Always build it to the same tag. Use that tag everywhere.

- You have the same image tag used everywhere
- Updates are made in the Dockerfile
- Changes are tracked by git

Alternatively, use a shell script that `docker tag`s what's necessary. You can even trigger it from a git hook.

Comment: Unfortunately there is one more issue I didn't think about yet: if for some reason you need to work on different branches simultaneously (like on CIs), this approach does not work without a complicated locking-mechanism, since the meaning of e.g. `busybox_default` would be part of a Docker-wide state. Putting it inside a text file (which gets read every time you access `busybox_default`) still solves this problem.
The best would be to have something like `docker --image-aliases=aliases.txt build <IMG>`

Comment: @frans I don't think you can solve this with Docker by itself. Maybe with Docker-in-Docker, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok, I do it now like this: starting from the `Dockerfile` approach I don't just `docker build` and subsequently use this "alias image" using `docker run`, but instead I'm doing something like `docker run $(docker build <dockerfile-dir> | grep "Successfully built" | awk '{print $3}')` every time I need it.
This way I don't introduce an extra file which is easier in most situations. Only Dockerfiles are a problem: here I have to inject the result of `docker build ..` using `ARG` and `--build-args`